# ListView Selected Position always resets

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working with a ListView trying to add/delete items. The addition bit was fairly easy, the removing though is proving to be trickier.
I was thinking to use a multiple choice list, but to start with something simpler  I chose a single choice mode just to test it out. 
I have an array of strings containing the items, an array adapter to notify when Data has changed.

```
    expenseAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                                            android.R.id.text1,
                                            expenseList);
    myListView.setAdapter(expenseAdapter); 
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position,
                long index) {



            ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, true);

            item.setSelected(true);
        }

    });
```

I have also added a listener for the item onClick Event. Visually the item gets selected/deselected the issue is when I click the button which triggers the deletion of the item the selected index in the list is always -1 although the item appears to be selected.

Delete button with onClick event

```
public boolean doDelete(View view)
{
    ListView myListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    String s=(String)myListView.getSelectedItem();

    expenseList.remove(s);
    expenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return true;
}
```

Any ideas what is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you performing deletion operation can you post that complete code here for better understanding.

Comment: Added the delete code.

Comment: You are getting -1 every time because you are removing one object from List with is not available.

Comment: Look into my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

xmlfile : https://www.dropbox.com/s/eky9zb275mgt4py/activity_list__addand_delete.xml

javaFile : https://www.dropbox.com/s/idqyyosbutgqqbs/List_AddandDelete.java

your selection ( focus ) is removed when ever you will shift your focus to button .

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code and understand that problem, you are getting -1 index when you are removing item from List because that item is not existing in that list so change your code please try this.

I changed **getSelectedItem()** to **getSelectedItemId()** here it will return selected item id instead of Item so you can remove that item from List based on item id which will be the Index of item in List.

```
public boolean doDelete(View view)
{
    ListView myListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    long id = myListView.getSelectedItemId();

    expenseList.remove(id);
    expenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return true;
}
```

Hope it will help you.